# Sorting an arrylist of circles based on radius

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, collections

Doing my final intro to java project. Still pretty new to Java (3 months). I'm crating two arrays and two arraylists of circles. Then i'm sorting one of the lists and one of the arraylists. I'm struggling to figure out how to sort them in ascending order by radius. Using Collections.sort(sortedList) and intellisense is saying i have an error "The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments
(ArrayList)". Also trying to sort the array as well and the error I'm getting is "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"  What am i doing wrong? Is this even the best way to approach the issue? Here's a snippet of my code.

```
public class CircleList
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    private Circle[] array = null;
    private Circle[] sortedArray = null;

    public ArrayList<Circle> list = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    public ArrayList<Circle> sortedList = new ArrayList<Circle>();

    /**
     * Constructor creates Array and List
     * 
     * @param max max size of list
     */
    public CircleList(int max)
    {

        int maxSize = max;

        int listSize = rand.nextInt(maxSize) + 1;
        System.out.println("List size: " + listSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            list.add(new Circle(rand.nextInt(100) + 1));
        }
        

        int arraySize = rand.nextInt(maxSize) + 1;
        System.out.println("Array size: " + arraySize);
        array = new Circle[arraySize];
        sortedArray = new Circle[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new Circle(rand.nextInt(100) + 1);
            sortedArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        
    }

    public void getList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Radius of circle " + i + " in the list: " + list.get(i).getRadius());
        }
    }

    public void getArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.println("Radius of circle " + i + " in the array :" + array[i].getRadius());
    }

    public  void setSortedList()
    {
        Collections.sort(sortedList);

    }

    public void getSortedArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++)
            System.out.println("Radius of circle " + i + " in the sorted array :" +        sortedArray[i].getRadius());
    }
    
    private void sortArray() {
        int startScan =0;
        int i =0;
        int minI = 0;
        double minRadius = 0;
        
        for (startScan =0; startScan < (sortedArray.length -1); startScan++) {
            minI = startScan;
            minRadius = sortedArray[startScan].getRadius();
            for(i = startScan +1; i< sortedArray.length;i++) {
                if (sortedArray[i].getRadius() < minRadius) {
                    minRadius = sortedArray[i].getRadius();
                    minI = i;
                }
            }
            sortedArray[minI].getRadius()=sortedArray[i].getRadius() ;
            minRadius = sortedArray[startScan].getRadius();
        }
    }
```

I tried using collections but I don't believe I'm reaching the radius, hence why the error but I may be wrong.
When trying to sort the array I feel a tad lost as to why the it's not working.

Comment: It would help us  if you could highlight the lines of your code that cause the errors. Maybe something like  `// **** <copy of error message> **** on following line:`

Comment: `sortedArray[minI].getRadius()=sortedArray[i].getRadius() ;`  `~.getRadius()` is a call to a method. It looks like a method that *returns* a value. But, you can't assign a value to it. It's not a variable.  We'd have to see something from your `Circle` class, but my guess  is you meant something like `sortedArray[minI].setRadius(sortedArray[i].getRadius()) ;`

Comment: Don't try to swap values inside a pair of `Object` types.  Instead, swap the references:   `if (foo[i].getMass() > foo[i+1].getMass()) { Foo tempFoo = foo[i]; foo[i] = foo [i+1]; foo[i+1] = tempFoo; }`

Comment: `Collections.sort(List)` must have a way of knowing  how to compare one item in the `List` with another item in the `List`. It needs code to tell it how to do that comparison. In this case, since `sortedList` is a `List<Circle>`, for `Collections.sort(sortedList);` to work, `Circle` should have an overridden `compareTo` method. `public class Circle implements Comparable<Circle> ... public int compareTo (Circle other) { ...`

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)  and https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: The circle class was provided to me to use, I did not write it.

Comment: Its a simple pojo with simple constructor that takes a radisu parameter, a PI field, and methods to get and set radius, diameter and circumference.

Comment: I believe that using Collections might not be the way to go for me. Not material we've covered yet and is beyond my level of understanding. I was just trying out stuff. I'll probably have to implement my own sorting algorithm  somehow.

Comment: `Collections.sort(sortedList, Comparator.comparingDouble(Circle::getRadius));` The same principle works for the array, `Arrays.sort(sortedArray, Comparator.comparingDouble(Circle::getRadius));` You can make a class implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html), as Old Dog Programmer suggested, but since a `Circle` has no *natural order* but rather, you want to sort by an particular chosen property, you should use a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to implement [*Selection sort algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) in the `sortArray()` method.

If my assumption is correct, then during each iteration of the inner `for`-loop, you need to find the `Circle` having the smallest radius that reside somewhere in between `startScan + 1` and the end of the array. And then you need to swap this element (i.e. element at position `minI`) with the element at index `startScan`.

That how it might be implemented.

```
private void sortArray() {
    int minI;
    double minRadius;
    
    for (int startScan = 0; startScan < sortedArray.length - 1; startScan++) {
        minI = startScan;
        minRadius = sortedArray[startScan].getRadius();
        for (int i = startScan + 1; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
            if (sortedArray[i].getRadius() < minRadius) {
                minRadius = sortedArray[i].getRadius();
                minI = i;
            }
        }
        CircleList.Circle temp = sortedArray[startScan];
        sortedArray[startScan] = sortedArray[minI];
        sortedArray[minI] = temp;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- There's a built-in functionality for sorting both `List`s and array. But I'm not sure if your assignment allows using it (*check your requirements*). Since Java 9 we have instance method `List.sort()` (and `Collections.sort()` is available from the very early versions of Java). And utility class `Arrays` offers a group of overloaded methods `sort()` which you can use to sort an array of any type.
- In order to use `List.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()` with a list or array of `Circle` instances, class `Circle` should either implement `Comparable` interface, or you need to provide a `Comparator` (*for more detail refer to the [official tutorial provided by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)*).